# IOS - How to show an upside "uʍop" text?

Tags: iphone

In the IOS GUI, I would like to place a textbox but it has to be upside down.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and use `CGAffineTransform` to rotate it 180 degrees

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)


[textbox setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
[textbox setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(180))];
```

By setting `anchorPoint` to `0.5` , `0.5` means we want the rotation apply to the center of the `textbox`

More explanations with details can be found [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1951182)